# Ruby - extending method with super using splat

Tags: ruby, super, splat

In **"Comprehensive Ruby programming course"** e-book I have a case when the child class method extends parents method. I am not completely aware how it works:

```
class Parent
  def initialize(foo:, bar:)
   @foo = foo
   @bar = bar
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def initialize(buzz:,**args)
   super(**args)
   @buzz = buzz
  end
end
```

I cant completely understand why we use splat here - `**args`.
In here `def initialize(buzz:,**args)` we are just telling `initialize` to take unknown number of key-value arguments, right? But what exactly this means `super(**args)`. To tell method to take those key-value arguments from the superclass method? Why not just like this:

```
class Child < Parent
  def initialize(buzz:)
   super
   @buzz = buzz
  end
end
```

After all, `super` tells to extend method with whatever there is in the parent, so why these splat args needed?

Comment: Did you *try* your solution? You'll get an error that should tell you exactly why the splat args are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`**args` in the parameter list simply means *"get all extra keyword arguments and put them in a hash, called `args`"*.

Conversely, `**args` when calling a method does the opposite - *"get this hash called `args` and pass keyword arguments with the corresponding names and values from that hash"*.

---

`super` without arguments will try to pass all arguments that the child method received. Hence if you have extra that the parent didn't expect, you will get an `ArgumentError`.

In your example, the parent expects only `foo:` and `bar:`, while the child also has `buzz:`.